# Calculating distance (pythagoras) and running count in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access, geolocation

I am trying to build a rather complicated query in SQL, and being a beginner i would immensely appreciate some help to build it.

I am trying to achieve the following:

### [image: population_postcodes table]

[image]

1/ Calculate the `distance` between a postcode in the target_postcodes table - say E1 1AA - and all the postcodes in the the population_postcodes table using Cartesian latitude and longitude coordinates using Pythagoras:

```
SQRT( POW(MY_Y_AXIS - Y_AXIS, 2) + POW(MY_X_AXIS-X_AXIS, 2) )
```

2/ Create a new column with those `distance` values,

```
not sure how to do that step
```

2-bis/ Sort postcodes in the `population_postcodes` by the `distance` value we obtained,

```
not sure how to do that step
```

3/ Beginning with the closest postcode, add the value in the population column to a running_count column **UNTIL** `running_count` > `Number_of_beds` of E1 1AA,

proposed query for running count - but missing the above breaking condition:

```
SELECT distance, Population,
 (SELECT sum(population_postcodes.Population)) AS Total

FROM population_postcodes
WHERE population_postcodes.distance <= T1.distance) AS Total

FROM population_postcodes AS T1
```

4/ Create a new table that contains the postcode E1 1AA (`target_postcode`) and the distance value of the last postcode added to our running count.

Finally, i would need to loop this query over the whole `target_postcodes` table.

Thank you for you very much for helping a newbie out!

Comment: This is SQL Server, but it may give you some ideas http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-zipcode-latitude-longitude-pr

Comment: Are you using MS Access or MySQL as your database?

Comment: i am using Access but i figure the sql query will be similar?

Comment: It will not be sufficiently similar, for example, the current answer will not run in MS Access. It is best remove the MySQL tag unless you want MySQL answers.

Comment: Could you please tell me how it differs / how i could correct the query?

Answer (score 0):

1., 2. To bring tables together and perform operations between them, you need to use Join
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html
otherwise your formula is correct. To create it as a column in your query, just write it in the projection(select) part.
Example:

```
select 
population_postcodes.*, 
target_postcodes.*, 
SQRT( POW(population_postcodes.longitude- target_postcodes.longitude, 2) + POW(population_postcodes.latitude-target_postcodes.latitude, 2) ) as distance
from population_postcodes JOIN target_postcodes
```

points 2 bis. End with Order by column_name asc/desc
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

point 3. Write everything as a `sub-query`, and select only what you need in the top query. Also look at `HAVING`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

point 4. look at ways to create tables and apply what you nearned

```
create table mytablename
select ... my projection columns
from ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: Adrian thanks so much, i'll try to implement this and let you know in a bit. Again thank you!