# Wrong number of arguments SQL MSACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am getting an error indicating the wrong number of arguments when I run the following query:

```
SELECT
population_postcodes.*, 
target_postcodes.*, 
SQR( EXP(population_postcodes.longitude- target_postcodes.longitude, 2) + EXP(population_postcodes.latitude-target_postcodes.latitude, 2) ) as distance
FROM population_postcodes INNER JOIN target_postcodes on Population_postcodes.Population_postcode = Target_postcodes.Target_postcode;
```

Could anyone please suggest how I can fix this?

I have also tried the following code:

```
SELECT Population_postcodes.*, Target_postcodes.* 

FROM population_postcodes
INNER JOIN target_postcodes
ON Population_postcodes.Population_postcode = Target_postcodes.Target_postcode
SQR( (population_postcodes.longitude- target_postcodes.longitude)^2 + (population_postcodes.latitude-target_postcodes.latitude)^2 ) as distance;
```

And this code:

```
     SELECT Population_postcodes.*, Target_postcodes.*, SQR( (population_postcodes.longitude- target_postcodes.longitude)^2 + (population_postcodes.latitude-target_postcodes.latitude)^2 ) as distance
FROM population_postcodes
INNER JOIN target_postcodes
ON Population_postcodes.Population_postcode = Target_postcodes.Target_postcode;
```

Comment: One idea would be to use the correct tags :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994005/calculating-distance-pythagoras-and-running-count-in-sql-query#comment31549134_20994005

Comment: Haha Remou I get it, trying to fix it now, will remember the advice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Exp needs one parameter, you give two.

Old: `EXP(population_postcodes.longitude- target_postcodes.longitude, 2)`

New: `(population_postcodes.longitude- target_postcodes.longitude)*(population_postcodes.longitude- target_postcodes.longitude)`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing...

```
EXP(<expression>, 2)
```

...to...

```
<expression>^2
```

In Access, the EXP function returns e (the base of natural logarithms) raised to a power.  To raise an expression to a power, use the ^ operator.

In your case, be careful to put brackets around the expression, for example...

```
(population_postcodes.longitude- target_postcodes.longitude)^2
```

...to force the power to be applied last.  By default, the ^ operator is evaluated before the - operator.

Comment: Dear brian thanks for the help, however its still not working. Here's my current query:

SELECT Population_postcodes.*, Target_postcodes.* 
FROM population_postcodes
INNER JOIN target_postcodes
ON Population_postcodes.Population_postcode = Target_postcodes.Target_postcode
SQR( (population_postcodes.longitude- target_postcodes.longitude)^2 + (population_postcodes.latitude-target_postcodes.latitude)^2 ) as distance;

Comment: Try moving the `distance` expression to the `SELECT` clause, as in something like: `SELECT Population_postcodes.*, Target_postcodes.*, SQR( (population_postcodes.longitude- target_postcodes.longitude)^2 + (population_postcodes.latitude-target_postcodes.latitude)^2 ) as distance FROM population_postcodes INNER JOIN target_postcodes ON Population_postcodes.Population_postcode = Target_postcodes.Target_postcode;`

Comment: for some reason it still yields an empty table with column names created representing both tables names and all of their columns as well as a new distance column...

Comment: Then there must be no records in `Population_postcodes` that have a `Population_postcode` equal to the `Target_postcode` of any record in `Target_postcodes`.