# enter parameter value with order by in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm getting a enter parameter value on `cooltable.distance` when Access executes `ORDER BY`, which is strange since distance is a column created in `cooltable`. What am I missing?

```
SELECT
target_postcodes.target_postcode,
population_postcodes.population_postcode,
cooltable.distance,
SQR( ( Population_postcodes.Longitude - target_postcodes.longitude)^2 + (Population_postcodes.Latitude - target_postcodes.latitude)^2 ) as distance

INTO
cooltable

FROM
Population_postcodes,
Target_postcodes


ORDER BY
cooltable.distance;
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to retrieve data from the `cooltable` before it's been created with the `into` statement. If it already exists you probably want to use `insert` instead of `select ... into`

Comment: that's what I thought. Any suggestions on how to fix it? Maybe nesting it somehow?

Comment: aren't you missing a join on your 2 tables?

Comment: This is your third question on an identical issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996713/wrong-number-of-arguments-sql-msaccess, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994005/calculating-distance-pythagoras-and-running-count-in-sql-query#comment31549134_20994005

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO CoolTable( col1, col2, col3 )
SELECT .....
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

Comment: number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Comment: no actually i had added a line in select that I deleted. It still asks me for the parameter value though

Comment: ok... then you have a mismatch of columns specified in the INSERT INTO CoolTable( Col1, col2, col3) and the SELECT.   In my example here we have 3.  So 3 columns on the INSERT and 3 columns on the SELECT

Comment: Yep i've solved that but still getting the parameter value prompt

Comment: is there a menu option for Parameters?  Did you manually add a parameter?  Maybe you should start over